# Responsive works on screen tester, but not on cellphone

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr6/

That's a wordpress site. Using bootstrap,
I've put entire design in two columns

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="side1"></div>
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div>
```

Not gonna put the styling here. Too much of it.

Also, using a WEN's Responsive Column Layout Shortcodes for inpost responsive columns.

Everything works perfectly on screen testers. Not on cellphones, though. These two main columns don't stack on each other, menu refuses to turn into responsive one (it does on the screen tester), and inpost columns start overflowing.

usually using this tester
http://quirktools.com/screenfly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` inside your `<head>` tag.

You can find a good explanation about the viewport meta tag [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972).

Answer (score 1):

use the following meta in your head tag

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```